# Connection refused error by soap-client curl while connecting to my zimbra server from cakephp2.6 app from my website?

Tags: php, curl, server, zimbra, cakephp-2.6

I am testing zimbra server.I have details of configured linux zimbra server like : ZIMBRA_LOGIN, ZIMBRA_PASS, ZIMBRA_SERVER, ZIMBRA_PORT
As in script showing on url below : 
Url : https://github.com/libersoft/zcs-php

I have defined my login details as on its documented in above url

```
define('ZIMBRA_LOGIN', 'my_username');
define('ZIMBRA_PASS', 'myPass');
define('ZIMBRA_SERVER', 'mymail.serverdomain.com');
define('ZIMBRA_PORT', '7071');
```

I have fill my login details, but it respond me back with this error.
I am unable to find where did i mistake, it only gives me this error :

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Bx5nzfr3qxekbjBXZF94clEwV3M.

Is there any reference for connecting and perform operations of create users for Linux Zimbra server from PHP or CakePHP application ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is mails.mytestingserver.com is unable to resolve.
Have you tried communicating using the IP address?

define('ZIMBRA_SERVER', 'mymail.serverdomain.com');
define('ZIMBRA_PORT', '7071');

Port 7071/9071 is the admin console, you would want to attempt to use port 80 or 443 here.

Comment: Well Thanks for reply khondhu i will try with that.

Comment: I have tried it but problem not fixed yet i have godaddy domain i think that might be issue because they have blocked firewall or we have to set proxy any way thanks for your time , will share it when got fixed.